# ImputError: No module named 'tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and wanted to code a simple application to practice a bit more but for whatever reason it is saying there is no module named 'tkinter'. I've tested to make sure tkinter is installed using python -m Tkinter and it works but tkinter won't work with my project. I am using pop_os! Linux and I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first_game.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Comment: Are you sure the Python version Visual Studio Code uses is the same as the command line `python`?

Comment: `Tkinter` is not the same as `tkinter`.

Comment: Yes, and they said that `Tkinter` works.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt when I try capitalized Tkinter in VS it doesn't even recognize it. If I try the same "python -m Tkinter" in terminal with a lowercase t it says "No module named tkinter"

Comment: Please add that info to your question! Also, clarify there what you do and in what environment. For example, I don't know what you mean with "doesn't even recognize it" as opposed to the previously mentioned error. Of course, if it doesn't work from the commandline, it's probably not going to work in VS code either, so you could perhaps remove that from your question altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capitalisation matters when it comes to names in Python. In Python 2, the library is called [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tkinter.html). In Python 3, it has been renamed [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) to be consistent with the rest of the standard library.

You can check which version of Python your command line is running with `python --version`, or by running the following script:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `python -m Tkinter` works, then you need to do `from Tkinter import *`. Case matters when importing packages.

However, if `python -m Tkinter` works that means you're using python 2.x which is no longer supported. It would be best to switch to python 3.x, in which case the package is named `tkinter` rather than `Tkinter`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think you're right. I never realized I was on python2, I just checked my version and I am indeed on 2. I'll upgrade now and get back to you. Definitely feel like I've made a rookie mistake here.

Comment: Whenever I check my version with `python --version` it says I am on 2.7.18 but if I do `python3 --version` it says I am on 3.9.5. I can get my program to run using terminal and manually doing it with `python3 first_game.py` but on VS it gives the error in the built in terminal. Does that mean VS is trying to run my programs with 2.x rather than 3.x? How can I change that?